# Java Scaling Font with AffineTransform

Tags: java

Anyone have an example snippet showing how to scale a Font using AffineTransform?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't really need an AffineTransform to do a simple font scale. You can use [`Font.deriveFont(float size)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont(float)) to geet a new `Font object with the specified size.

But I suppose you could use [`AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(double sx, double sy)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getScaleInstance%28double,%20double%29) and apply the transform to your `Graphics2D` object (assuming you have one) if you'd rather. It really depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

From memory:

```
Font tallerFont = font.deriveFont(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(1.0, 2.0));
```